# R: Caret package: AUC ("ROC") standard error from cross validation

Tags: r, auc, method-comparison

This seems like a basic questions, so I'm likely missing the big picture here...

I would like to know the AUC of each fold of a cross-validation performed in Caret's train function, in order to calculate the standard error of the AUC.  Here is the typical output, which I assume provides the average "ROC" (AUC) across each of the five folds:

```
Generalized Linear Model 

85537 samples
   31 predictor
    2 classes: 'X0', 'X1' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (5 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 68430, 68429, 68430, 68430, 68429 
Resampling results:

  ROC       Sens      Spec     
  0.918912  0.834479  0.8450047
```

Other functions (e.g., cv.glmnet in the glmnet package) seems to output the standard error.

```
Call:  cv.glmnet(x = train.data.x, y = train.data.y, type.measure = c("auc"),      nfolds = 5, alpha = 1, family = "binomial") 

Measure: AUC 

       Lambda Measure        SE Nonzero
min 0.0000504  0.9027 0.0006507     166
1se 0.0003901  0.9021 0.0006224     160
```

**Is there a statistical reason why Caret's train function does not output this as a default?**  I believe this would help to show the variation in the model performance for different models (e.g., logistic regression and Lasso).

I am likely operating under some false assumptions here.

Comment: It might just be that cv.glmnet actually uses that value to generate the "1se" model, which is the sparsest model with a performance measure within 1 standard error of the optimum. Caret doesn't seem to use the standard error for anything, so perhaps they just omit the calculation.

Comment: These comments might help with an explanation: "You can certainly summarize a ROC curve using a c-statistic or the AUC, but calculating confidence intervals and performing inference using c-statistics is well understood due to its relation to the Wilcoxon U-statistic.  It's generally fairly well accepted that you can estimate the variability in ROC curves using the bootstrap cf Pepe Etzione Feng. This is a nice approach because the ROC curve is an empirical estimate and the bootstrap is non-parametric."

Comment: It looks like you can examine some of that information:
https://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#exploring-and-comparing-resampling-distributions

Comment: I don't think there is a generally accepted way of estimating SE for an AUC - e.g: Hanley and McNeil (1982) provide a closed-form expression that in my opinion is often preferable to bootstrapping. Also note that every instance is exactly predicted once - Caret is probably reporting the AUC over all samples (not the mean).

Comment: Also found this: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-January/225327.html

Comment: And this, R’s pROC package’s ci.auc() function.  It uses a 2,000 stratified bootstrap replicate.

Comment: `fit$resample$ROC`     
----should provide the list